# MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

SOMETIMES when our team connect the mongodb database at localhost by these codes:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const CONN = 'mongodb://name:password@www.wecard.io:27017/myproject'

const option = {
    socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
    keepAlive: true,
    reconnectTries: 30000
};

mongoose.connect(CONN, option).then(
  () => { console.log('It is good: ' + CONN); },
  (err) => {
    console.error('Error: ' + err);
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

ONE of our teammates get this error:

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [www.website.com:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 46.101.98.56:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/liubaobao/Desktop/WeCard/models/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:505:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/liubaobao/Desktop/WeCard/models/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:329:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/liubaobao/Desktop/WeCard/models/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:245:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [www.website.com:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 46.101.98.56:27017]'
```

And at the same time if we connect it on cloud server, it has been always good so far. So anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Looks more like a networking issue than code or setup. This really isn't the place for questions about networking and you might have more luck on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com) but it's probably still more about diagnosing the single network issue anyway. You really should be upgrading your MongoDB instance, as 2.6 passed end of life for official support some time ago

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have noticed I can't upgrade to 3.6 directly. So if you know any tutorials for upgrade form 2.6 to 3.6, it will be great!

Comment: There are instructions in the official documentation. I believe you need to "at least" upgrade to 3.0 as an intermediary step. Depending on what you have done there is likely  an index upgrade procedure in there as well.